# How to load multiple 3D models dynamically xna

Tags: xna, 3d, model-loader

I want to load multiple 3D models `.fbx` at the same time in my map display.
I can load First Model but when I use ContentBuilder to Load another Model, I Got Error in `effect.EnableDefaultLighting ();` 
This my load function

```
private void loadToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            // Default to the directory which contains our content files.
            string assemblyLocation = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            string relativePath = Path.Combine(assemblyLocation, "../../../../Content");
            string contentPath = Path.GetFullPath(relativePath);
            fileDialog.InitialDirectory = contentPath;
            fileDialog.Title = "Load Model";
            fileDialog.Filter = "Model Files (*.fbx;*.x)|*.fbx;*.x|" +
                                "FBX Files (*.fbx)|*.fbx|" +
                                "X Files (*.x)|*.x|" +
                                "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                LoadModel(fileDialog.FileName);
            }
        }
        void LoadModel(string fileName)
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            // Unload any existing model.
            editorDesign1.Model = null;
           // editorDesign1.CurrentModel.Model = null;
            contentManager.Unload();
            // Tell the ContentBuilder what to build.
            contentBuilder.Clear();
            contentBuilder.Add(fileName, "Model", null, "ModelProcessor");
            // Build this new model data.
            string buildError = contentBuilder.Build();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(buildError))
            {
                // If the build succeeded, use the ContentManager to
                // load the temporary .xnb file that we just created.
              editorDesign1.Model = contentManager.Load<Model>("Model");
              // editorDesign1.CurrentModel.Model = contentManager.Load<Model>("Model");
            }
            else
            {
                // If the build failed, display an error message.
                MessageBox.Show(buildError, "Error");
            }

            Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        }
```

and this is my Draw `model function`

```
public void DrawModel()
        {
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in Model.Meshes)
            {
                foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                {
                    effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                    effect.World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position) * Matrix.CreateRotationX(Rotation.X) * Matrix.CreateScale(Scale) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(Rotation.Y) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation.Z);

                    effect.View = view;
                    effect.Projection = projection;
                }

                mesh.Draw();
            }
        }
```

The problem is when I create two object from my model class and use ContentBuilder to Load another Model I get an exception `AccessViolationException was Unhandled` `Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt` 
 and get another exception `NullReferenceException was unhandled`

Can anyone help me tho solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can find several problems, mainly with your workflow. First it looks like your editor can only show one model at a time anyway. Every time the dialog is launched the editor is cleared. You should use an array or a list to contain the models that are in the editor.

```
editorDesign1.Model = null;
...
editorDesign1.Model = contentManager.Load<Model>("Model");
```

Should become...

```
editorDesign1.Models = new List<Model>(); // or Models.Clear();
...
editorDesign1.Models.Add(contentManager.Load<Model>("Model"));
```

Also, you shouldn't clear the list upon loading if you want multiple files.

Your `AccessViolationException` is probably caused by the fact that when you build a model it saves it to the `Model` file. When you try to load another model, it also tries to write to the `Model` file which already exists and is protected, so the error is thrown.

You should either delete the file after it is loaded to memory or use unique names for the binary file.